# Dynamically modify the iOS project .mobileprovision

Tags: dynamic, xcodebuild, compiled, mobileprovision

Now,I have a big question.I'm doing iOS dynamically compiled function, I want to use an iOS project, compile several different ipa file, use the Enterprise so that these items can be installed to the phone, I use xcodebuild command. But I do not know how to dynamically generate .mobileprovision file. I do not want every time manually generated from the Apple Developer Center

Comment: I just want to do mass unified template APP, so think about how to configure dynamic .mobileprovision file, is there any good options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.mobileprovision` files comply with [RFC 3852](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852) "Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS)".  In addition to the plain-text signing identities, app identifiers, entitlements, permitted test device UDIDs, and other related metadata, these files are cryptographically signed by Apple at the time they are generated on the Certificates, Identities, and Profiles tool.  As only Apple holds the cryptographic keys that protect these documents, you will not be able to dynamically alter these files yourself -- you will have to work with the Certificates, Identities, and Profiles tool to be able to generate, request, download, and install profiles Apple generates.

Alternatively, the Certificates, Identities, and Profiles tool permits you to define what is called a Wildcard App ID (ex: `com.mycompany.apps.*`) that would allow you to use that one provisioning profile with apps under that app id tree:

`com.mycompany.apps.myfirstapp`
`com.mycompany.apps.yetanotherapp`

would both work, while:

`com.mycompany.someotherapp`

would require a different provisioning profile.  Use of Wildcard App Ids also limits the kinds of entitlement based services you are permitted to use -- notably things like Push Notifications, Apple Pay, In-App Purchases, and Game Center are specifically disallowed under wildcard provisioning.  If your app template requires use of these restricted entitlement based services, wildcard provisioning is not a viable solution and you will have to fall back to interacting with the Certificates, Profiles, and Identities tool.

Comment: Hi Bryan Musial ,thanks for your answer. i will do it as you say, Then reply to my results. thanks.

Comment: Hi Bryan Musial, I have done like that. but , there was a problem, when i defined Wildcard App ID (ex:[com.mycompany.apps.*] ), i can't create In-House distribution provisioning(i had a iOS Development Enterprise Program).I can't use Ad-Hoc, because i do not know all the devices' uuid. I want to create In-House ,then i could Archive my iOS project. i want to use the ipa that run on iPhone. how can i do it. I wish to receive your reply  ,thanks very much.

Comment: I just ran through the same procedure using my enterprise account and was able to generate an In-House Provisioning Profile for a Wildcard appId and then deploy the resulting IPA to a device suggesting you have mismatched AppIds either in your project or in the settings on the Certificates, Identities, and Profiles tool.  Unfortunately, there is too little information in your question to offer better guidance for what to check next.

Comment: thanks for your replay. my question is that i could't use my Wildcard appId to generate an In-House Provisioning Profile.Now , i have an Wildcard appId(com.mycompany.*) ,but, when i generated an In-House Provisioning Profile, in Select-App-ID step, i could't choose my Wildcard appId, So I can not do the next operation.Here is the corresponding picture:<img src="http://7rfgqd.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/11.png" width="100" height="100"><img src="http://7rfgqd.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/22.png">

Comment: Again, I have a different behavior.  I can very much generate In-House provisioning profiles via a wildcard app id, so I can not replicate the behavior you are observing locally.  My recommendation still stands, but you will need to work out whatever issue is currently blocking your provisioning center before you can proceed.  You also need to verify that how you are planning to use those Enterprise signed builds is within the limits of your enterprise license -- it is very easy to inadvertently breach your license agreement and be subject to Apple's license revocation process.

Comment: thanks very much, i will do it again and again until i find the reason. i will reply my results.Confirm it as soon as possible.thanks again.

Comment: Hi Bryan Musial,i have already know why i can't do it. For a new account  that the Apple inc. has been blocked this feature. I have tested it. So, i can't do it.My account is newer. thanks a lot.I will be thinking about other programs